Как исправить ошибку Route [admin.index] not defined.?
Что я делаю не так в Laravel, что не видит маршрут который я указываю в views ?
В файле routes\web.php подключаю группу маршрутов
$request_array = config("request.request_array");

if ($request_array[0] == 'sw-admin')
{
    View::addLocation(app_path() . '/admin/frontend/views');
    View::addNamespace('Admin', app_path()."/Admin/Frontend/Views/");
    Route::prefix('sw-admin')->middleware('AdminPanelMiddleware')->namespace("App\Admin\Controllers")->group('../app/admin/web.php');
} 

В app/admin/web.php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

Route::get('', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');
Route::get('', 'AdminController@settings')->name('admin.settings');

В app\admin\controllers\AdminControllers.php
namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\Settings;
use App\Modules\News\Database\Models\News;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //dd('new admin');

        return View::make('Admin::index');
    }
}

В app\admin\frontend\views\parts\header.blade.php
<a href="{{ route('admin.index') }}" class="logo">


Это что такое и как работает? $request_array = config("request.request_array");  if ($request_array[0] == 'sw-admin'), в конфигах обычно хранятся статические файлы, какое отношение это имеет к роутингу?

@Jour ну, я решил начать с первого что вызывает вопросы))
